# "return type is incomplete" error when building aws c++ config library on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, build, aws-sdk

I tried to build aws c++ config library on a Ubuntu 14.04 Vm with gcc and g++ 4.8.2 (this compiler version is prerequisite for me).
When I run make with std=c++11 I get the following error for file ConfigServiceClient.cpp :

```
/home/user/Libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-1.2.22/aws-cpp-sdk-config/source/ConfigServiceClient.cpp: In member function 'virtual Aws::ConfigService::Model::DeleteConfigRuleOutcomeCallable Aws::ConfigService::ConfigServiceClient::DeleteConfigRuleCallable(const Aws::ConfigService::Model::DeleteConfigRuleRequest&) const':
/home/user/Libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-1.2.22/aws-cpp-sdk-config/source/ConfigServiceClient.cpp:138:119: error: return type 'Aws::ConfigService::Model::DeleteConfigRuleOutcomeCallable {aka class std::future<Aws::Utils::Outcome<Aws::NoResult, Aws::Client::AWSError<Aws::ConfigService::ConfigServiceErrors> > >}' is incomplete
 DeleteConfigRuleOutcomeCallable ConfigServiceClient::DeleteConfigRuleCallable(const DeleteConfigRuleRequest& request) const
```

The code line in ConfigServiceClient.cpp  that the error is reported is :

```
DeleteConfigRuleOutcomeCallable ConfigServiceClient::DeleteConfigRuleCallable(const DeleteConfigRuleRequest& request) const
{
  auto task = Aws::MakeShared< std::packaged_task< DeleteConfigRuleOutcome() > >(ALLOCATION_TAG, [this, request](){ return this->DeleteConfigRule(request); } );
  auto packagedFunction = [task]() { (*task)(); };
  m_executor->Submit(packagedFunction);
  return task->get_future();
}
```

While the definition of the function in ConfigServiceClient.h is

```
virtual Model::DeleteConfigRuleOutcomeCallable DeleteConfigRuleCallable(const Model::DeleteConfigRuleRequest& request) const;

    /**
     * <p>Deletes the specified AWS Config rule and all of its evaluation results.</p>
     * <p>AWS Config sets the state of a rule to <code>DELETING</code> until the
     * deletion is complete. You cannot update a rule while it is in this state. If you
     * make a <code>PutConfigRule</code> or <code>DeleteConfigRule</code> request for
     * the rule, you will receive a <code>ResourceInUseException</code>.</p> <p>You can
     * check the state of a rule by using the <code>DescribeConfigRules</code>
     * request.</p><p><h3>See Also:</h3>   <a
     * href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/config-2014-11-12/DeleteConfigRule">AWS
     * API Reference</a></p>
     *
         * Queues the request into a thread executor and triggers associated callback when operation has finished.
         */
```

This kind of error is related with gcc version (c++ standard support issue) or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [readme for the AWS C++ SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/README.md) (emphasis mine):

> Minimum Requirements:
>
> - Visual Studio 2013 or later [...]
> - OR GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) **4.9 or later**
> - OR Clang 3.3 or later

Your gcc version is too old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you by any chance recognize the feature which is not supported by gcc 4.8.2 that leads to this error since auto-typed variables are supported since 4.8.1?

Comment: @dk13 I am not sure, but the compiler complains about an incomplete type,  and the type in question is the first use of `std::future` in such a context within that translation unit, so I would assume that it is some incompatibility in the implementation of `std::future` in that particular version of gcc.